# Filter object returning an attribute

Tags: python, filter

I'm trying to filter an object returning a list of a specific attribute. Look what I've tried:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

x = Foo(1,2)
y = Foo(1,3)
z = Foo(2,4) 
result = filter(lambda f: f.b if f.a == 1 else None, [x,y,z])
print(list(result))
```

I was expecting a list like this `[2, 3]`, but It returns me a list of `foo` objects. Is there a way to do it using just `filter` other function? I'd like to avoid using `map` and `filter`, for example.

Comment: The lambda should be a boolean expression, you are returning the value of `Foo.b`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension

```
result = [i.b for i in [x,y,z] if i.a == 1]
```

Using `filter` it would take two steps: one to filter out the objects where `i.a != 1` and the second to pull the `.b` out of each object (which would require `map`).